# Can't create the child class of CCSprite in Cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

I want to create a new class which is a child class of `CCSprite`. But it doesn't work.

It got the error **CCBullet does not name a type**

Please take a look and tell me some your ideas to solve my problems. Thanks.

**CCBullet.h**

```
#ifndef __GameplayScene_H__
#define __GameplayScene_H__

#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "common/Define.h"

#if ENABLE_PHYSICS_BOX2D_DETECT
#include "../../Box2DTestBed/GLES-Render.h"
#include "Box2D/Box2D.h"
#elif ENABLE_PHYSICS_CHIPMUNK_DETECT
#include "chipmunk.h"
#endif

USING_NS_CC;

class CCBullet : public cocos2d::CCSprite
{
public:
    static CCBullet* create(int bulletID, const char *filePath);
};

#endif
```

**CCBullet.cpp**

```
#include "common/Define.h"
USING_NS_CC;
using namespace cocos2d;
using namespace cocos2d::extension;

CCBullet* CCBullet::create(int bulletID, const char *filePath){
    CCBullet *pobSprite = new CCSprite();
    if (pobSprite && pobSprite->initWithFile(filePath))
    {       
        pobSprite->mBulletID = bulletID;    
        pobSprite->mAngle = 0;
        pobSprite->mSpeed = 0;
        pobSprite->mStrength = 0;
        pobSprite->mPushBack = 0;
        pobSprite->mCritical = 0;
        pobSprite->mFanShoot = 0;
        pobSprite->mSpread = 0;
        pobSprite->autorelease();
        return pobSprite;
    }
    CC_SAFE_DELETE(pobSprite);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? I guess you have to instantiate a CCBullet and not a CCSprite. Please change `new CCSprite()` for `new CCBullet()`.

Comment: @LaurentZubiaur: It got the error CCBullet does not name a type as I updated in my question. Do you have any ideas for this error?

Comment: Please double check that CCBullet.h is included in CCBullet.cpp.

Comment: @LaurentZubiaur: I did

Comment: I tested you code and the include "CCBuller.h" is missing (though I don't know what's in "common/Define.h"). Plus the code "CCBullet *pobSprite = new CCSprite();" won't compile.

Comment: I included the "CCBuller.h" and other definitions in the Define.h

Comment: Did you try changing `new CCSprite` to `CCBullet *pobSprite = new CCBullet()`?

Comment: I did but still the same error. I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested with the code below and it compile without problem. There must be something else in your code that cause the issue.

CCBullet.h

```
#ifndef __GameplayScene_H__
#define __GameplayScene_H__

#include "cocos2d.h"
/// #include "common/Define.h"

#if ENABLE_PHYSICS_BOX2D_DETECT
#include "../../Box2DTestBed/GLES-Render.h"
#include "Box2D/Box2D.h"
#elif ENABLE_PHYSICS_CHIPMUNK_DETECT
#include "chipmunk.h"
#endif

USING_NS_CC;

class CCBullet : public cocos2d::CCSprite
{
public:
    static CCBullet* create(int bulletID, const char *filePath);
protected:
    float mBulletID;
    float mAngle;
    float mSpeed;
    float mStrength;
    float mPushBack;
    float mCritical;
    float mFanShoot;
    float mSpread;
};

#endif
```

CCBullet.cpp

```
/// #include "common/Define.h"
#include "CCBullet.h"
USING_NS_CC;
using namespace cocos2d;
/// using namespace cocos2d::extension;

CCBullet* CCBullet::create(int bulletID, const char *filePath){
    CCBullet *pobSprite = new CCBullet();
    if (pobSprite && pobSprite->initWithFile(filePath))
    {
        pobSprite->mBulletID = bulletID;
        pobSprite->mAngle = 0;
        pobSprite->mSpeed = 0;
        pobSprite->mStrength = 0;
        pobSprite->mPushBack = 0;
        pobSprite->mCritical = 0;
        pobSprite->mFanShoot = 0;
        pobSprite->mSpread = 0;
        pobSprite->autorelease();
        return pobSprite;
    }
    CC_SAFE_DELETE(pobSprite);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Let me try again. One more, I should use pobSprite->mAngle = 0; or this->mAngle = 0 ?

Comment: In CCBullet::create you must use pobSprite->mAngle (it's a static method so you can't use `this`).

Comment: I know the cause of the error. I have to be declare the CCBullet before other classes which call CCBullet. However, I got this error undefined reference to 'CCBullet::create(int, char const*)'

Comment: I solved the problem. I have to put the CCBullet.h above the header of the class I use CCBullet. Thanks